# How can we disable implicit casting in MSVC C++?

Tags: visual-c++

I am working on an embedded project. When I compile my solution in the embedded tool chain, it gives me errors related to implicit conversion as it's not supported.

I have an equivalent desktop application on MSVC. I wish to replicate the same situation in MSVC solution. But the MSVC by default is able to do implicit conversion.

Is there a way to disable implicit conversion in MSVC?

Comment: your are getting any warning while conversion? Which visual studio version? and one code example of implicit cast from your project.

Answer (score 1):

For conversions such as `double` to `int`, where you would normally get:

> warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss
>   of data

you can 'convert' this warning to an error, using:

```cpp
#pragma warning(error:4244)
```

Thus, the following code will fail to compile:

```cpp
#pragma warning(error:4244)
double foo;
int bar;
bar = foo;
```

> error C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of
>   data

There are similar warnings for other implicit conversions, which can be converted to errors in the same way. For, example, conversions between `signed` and `unsigned` integer types elicit warning number `4365`.

*Note: You would also need the warning level set to at least /W4, in order for the warnings to show. Alternatively, if you don't want to be bothered by all the 'extra' warnings this may generate, you can explicitly enable any selected warning with: `#pragma warning(enable:4244)`. (I would recommend the former, especially when building for an embedded platform.)*